# Script provisioning of ubuntu host?

Tags: linux, script

I re-install ubuntu from time to time on a remote server. Each time I do that I always go through: creating some standard users, ssh keys, install java, install git, etc.

So I would like to script this somehow. Before just hacking away in e.g. bash is there better ways to do this?

I have considered writing a dockerfile but I don't really want my host (1 layer) to run as a container. I also looked at:

https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/index.html

but again I don't want my host to be virtual.

Comment: You are looking for 'Configuration Management tools'.  There are many.  Ansible, salt, puppet, chef, etc...  Pick one.  These days ansible is my favorite, but they are all pretty functional.

Comment: Yes was also considering ansible but seems it’s based on SSH https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-ansible-on-ubuntu-14-04 I just need to be able to configure a host machine not listen/run changes over SSH

Comment: Ansible playblooks can easily be applied against the local host. Using SSH is not required.  In fact the 'ansible-pull' way of running it is completely designed on the idea that it will be running against the local host.

Comment: Ok so it can be used in a “one off”, instead of in a running daemon mode?

Comment: Yes all those various tools I mentioned have method of apply adhoc commands.  Here is a simple ansible example.  https://gist.github.com/zoredache/59feed207a17f9e92f3ae1dd33321275

Comment: I just found that python needs to be install on all my remote machines before I can use ansible:http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-python-pathing-not-having-a-python-2-x-in-usr-bin-python-on-a-remote-machine so the idea of using ansible is sort lost when I manully have to do that first. I think I will stick to plain bash scripting, all machines have that guaranteed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68930/discussion-between-u123-and-zoredache).